# Is the Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL protected by brute force attack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to know that whether Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL is protected from brute force attack.

For example, if I am the only person who knows the Pre-signed URL, is it extremely unlikely that somebody use brute force attack and access to bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it is extremely unlikely, because presigned URLs allow for **temporary** access (up to 7 days depending on the credentials). The URL looks like this and encodes the credentials as query parameters.

```sh
s3 presign s3://bucket/object.txt
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/object.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA2BFBCSRBEESRYSW4%2F20210129%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210129T124141Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=95285dbaedbd458eaf27e6b4ef0f05d905a2079934aad082372dcbbdf33ead9f
```

Judge for yourself if you think it's possible to guess these credentials with a correct digital signature before it expires. Personally I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: Agree - that URL should be protected and would be next to impossible to guess.

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct in assuming that it is almost impossible to calculate a 64-digit secret combination in 7 days?

Comment: You might want to ask on crypto.stackexchange.com - I'm not an expert, but I wouldn't sleep well at night if that was remotely possible :D

Answer (score 0):

If you protect your URL and only give it to someone with a business need during the time period when its open (this can be configured), its highly unlikely that someone will use that URL to perform an online attack.